# Crash with urbanairship in android (when app is not in foreground)

Tags: android

Hi i am getting crashed when app is not in foreground or when we press back key to send app to back stack. And later when app receives the push notification from server at that point app crashes.
below is the stack trace of crash happneing

And help would be helpfull.

---

```
01-13 16:46:17.329: E/UA AP(16021): Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: null
01-13 16:46:17.330: E/UA AP(16021): Unable to takeOff automatically
01-13 16:46:17.338: W/dalvikvm(16021): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411609a8)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2520)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1416)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.urbanairship.push.PushService.acquireWakeLock(Unknown Source)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.urbanairship.push.PushService.runGcmIntentInService(Unknown Source)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2513)
01-13 16:46:17.348: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    ... 11 more
01-13 16:46:19.153: I/Process(16021): Sending signal. PID: 16021 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please provide code segment where this exception occur ..

Comment: You just have a nullpointer somewhere in the code that handles the received push. Start a debug process, add some breakpoints in your Service/BroadcastReceiver and send yourself a notification with urban airship.

Answer (score 1):

You may be doing your UrbanAirship setup in an activity instead of in your app.

I have this stuff in onCreate() in my Application and it fixed crashes like this.

```
UAirship.takeOff(this);
PushManager.enablePush();
String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
Logger.info("My Application onCreate - App APID: " + apid);
PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
```